# Cannot Install GO.db in BiocManager

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor

I've had a quick look through other posts, but couldn't find one with the same errors even though some appear to be somewhat common error messages, so apologies if I did miss a previous thread.

I am trying to install the BioConductor package "GO.db", but keep getting the error message:

```
> BiocManager::install("GO.db") Bioconductor version 3.8 (BiocManager
> 1.30.4), R 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) Installing package(s) 'GO.db' installing the source package ‘GO.db’
> 
> trying URL
> 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/data/annotation/src/contrib/GO.db_3.7.0.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 31820876 bytes (30.3 MB)
> downloaded 30.3 MB
> 
> * installing *source* package 'GO.db' ... Warning in file.copy(f, instdir, TRUE) :   problem copying .\NAMESPACE to
> C:\Users\Name\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\GO.db\NAMESPACE: Permission
> denied Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :   cannot open
> file 'C:/Users/Name/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/GO.db/DESCRIPTION':
> Permission denied Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :   
> cannot open the connection ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION
> failed for package 'GO.db'
> * removing 'C:/Users/Name/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/GO.db' In R CMD INSTALL
> 
> The downloaded source packages are in
>         ‘C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeYicUm\downloaded_packages’
> installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: class,
> codetools,   Matrix Update old packages: 'assertthat', 'mgcv'
```

I've tried reinstalling BiocManager, I've kept deleting the directories I've been told to. I've even tried running R as the administrator. But all these attempts garner the same error messages. I've seen a suggestion to use `R CMD INSTALL` with some command about locking, but since this is a BioConductor package, this solution appears to be unavailable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to download the package through several ways, and trying to install from a local file, I still had no luck.

For reasons unbeknown to me, still, I had to reduce the file protection with my antivirus software. R was already on the list of programs allowed to modify my files, but for whatever reason, it was still being blocked, and only for the instillation of the package `GO.db` - though I imagine I'll find a few more of these cases in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This technique worked for me.

1) BiocManager::install("Biobase")

2) BiocManager::install("GO.db")

Respond "y" when it asks if you want to update all packages.

3) BiocManager::valid("GO.db")

> [TRUE]

[TRUE] will appear if the update was a success.

4) library(WGCNA)

More than likely, you have to update more than one package.  Run step 4, then look at the warning text.  It told me that I also had to update "impute" and "preprocessCore."  I resolved both of these issues by repeating steps 1-3 for both packages.

If you update all of the packages correctly, you will see the following text when you reach step 4.  At this point, WGCNA is successfully installed.

> library(WGCNA);

Attaching package: ‘WGCNA’

The following object is masked from ‘package:IRanges’:

```
cor
```

The following object is masked from ‘package:S4Vectors’:

```
cor
```

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

```
cor
```

Warning message:
package ‘WGCNA’ was built under R version 3.6.3